# How to change EchoMode of QLineEdit between Normal and Password

Tags: python, qt, qpushbutton, qlineedit, pyqt6

I am writing a little program, but the buttons don't work
as I expected.

I wish the text to change state when I click on the button of that text.

Here is the code to test it:

```
from sys import exit
from sys import argv
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget, QLineEdit

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.screenWidth = 1920
        self.screenHeight = 1080
        self.windowWidth = 1000
        self.windowHeight = 800
        self.setWindowTitle("test 19")
        self.setGeometry((self.screenWidth - self.windowWidth) // 2, (self.screenHeight - self.windowHeight) // 2, self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)
        self.initUi()
    
    def initUi(self) -> None:
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        headLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        nameLabel = QLabel("Name")
        headLayout.addWidget(nameLabel)
        mainLayout.addItem(headLayout)
        row1 = Row("google.com")
        mainLayout.addItem(row1.returnValues())
        row2 = Row("yahoo.com")
        mainLayout.addItem(row2.returnValues())
        for i in range(20):
            rowi = Row(f"{i}")
            mainLayout.addItem(rowi.returnValues())
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

class Row():
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.rowLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.nameLineEdit = QLineEdit(f"{name}")
        self.nameLineEdit.setDisabled(True)
        self.rowLayout.addWidget(self.nameLineEdit)
        self.hiddenOrShowButton = QPushButton("")
        self.hiddenOrShowButton.clicked.connect(self.hiddenOrShow)
        self.rowLayout.addWidget(self.hiddenOrShowButton)
    
    def returnValues(self) -> QHBoxLayout:
        return self.rowLayout
    
    def hiddenOrShow(self) -> None:
        if self.nameLineEdit.echoMode() == QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password:
            self.nameLineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Normal)
        else:
            self.nameLineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    exit(app.exec())
```

I expect the text to change state when I click on the button of that text.

Comment: `rowi` gets destroyed as soon as the loop iterates again or `initUi` returns, and its connected functions along with it. Frankly, I don't really see the point of that `Row` class, since you're using it like that: you're not keeping any reference to it, so how do you suppose it to be persistent? Either directly subclass from QHBoxLayout, or from QWidget, used as a container: they are QObjects, and they become persistent when reparented. Also, as [the documentation explains](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem), you should **not** use `addItem()`, but `addWidget()` or `addLayout()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to subclass `QHBoxLayout`, as suggested by musicamante in the comments, and your `Row` class isn't that far off from doing just that.

The only changes that really need to be made are to add in the subclass reference in your `Row` to `Row(QHBoxLayout)`, then would want to remove the `self.rowLayout` line because the `Row` class would become the layout. and you would change all the references to it to just `self` instead of `self.rowLayout`.

For example:

```
from sys import exit
from sys import argv
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget, QLineEdit

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.screenWidth = 1920
        self.screenHeight = 1080
        self.windowWidth = 1000
        self.windowHeight = 800
        self.setWindowTitle("test 19")
        self.setGeometry((self.screenWidth - self.windowWidth) // 2, (self.screenHeight - self.windowHeight) // 2, self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self) -> None:
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        headLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        nameLabel = QLabel("Name")
        headLayout.addWidget(nameLabel)
        mainLayout.addLayout(headLayout)
        row1 = Row("google.com")   # the row now is the layout
        mainLayout.addLayout(row1)   # so you add it directly to the main layout
        row2 = Row("yahoo.com")
        mainLayout.addLayout(row2)   # use addLayout instead of addItem
        for i in range(20):
            rowi = Row(f"{i}")
            mainLayout.addLayout(rowi)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

class Row(QHBoxLayout):  # use subclass declaration
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.nameLineEdit = QLineEdit(f"{name}")
        self.nameLineEdit.setDisabled(True)  
        self.addWidget(self.nameLineEdit)    # add the widget to self
        self.hiddenOrShowButton = QPushButton("")   
        self.hiddenOrShowButton.clicked.connect(self.hiddenOrShow)
        self.addWidget(self.hiddenOrShowButton)   # same thing here

    # the returnValues method can be removed.

    def hiddenOrShow(self) -> None:
        if self.nameLineEdit.echoMode() == QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password:
            self.nameLineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Normal)
        else:
            self.nameLineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    exit(app.exec())
```